# Book recommendation that goes over how the bible is compiled based on manuscripts

Tags: bible, manuscript

I have read about how the King's James bible and (I think) the NIV bible differ.  Some verses from the Kings james bible were removed as they were not present in earlier manuscripts.

Anyhow, are there any research papers or books that go over each verse and notes exactly which manuscript contains the verse?

I know that this is actually an on-going process, where some verses are removed, and then the verse above is split into 2 to keep the verse count the same etc.  I would like to know exactly what was done, and by whom, and which manuscript was used as the source.

Comment: It's important to understand that verses from the KJV were never removed.  There are some Greek manuscripts that have the verses, and some that do not.  So, either some explanatory phrases crept INTO some manuscripts OR some phrases crept OUT.  Wikipedia has a summary of the major variants, which is pretty good actually.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_major_textual_variants_in_the_New_Testament  They also have a much more comprehensive list:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textual_variants_in_the_New_Testament#Gospel_of_Matthew

Answer (score 3):

Bruce Metzger's *A Textual Commentary on the Greek New Testament* is a well-known book that accomplishes what you asked about.

I'd also recommend procuring some critical apparati. These list the variants and allow the reader to form their own conclusions, for the most part. Two well-known apparati are Nestle-Aland's NA26/ 27/ 28 Greek New Testament, as well as Constantin Tischendorf's critical apparatus.